# Updates I made within the background worker do not appear in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, backgroundworker, ddd-repositories

I have two entities in the project as follows and I can update these entities within a service.

[image]

[image]

`UpdateAsync` service:

[image]

`UpdateAsync` method works as expected.

However, although I wrote similar codes, the change I made in the background worker only affects Monitoring. In short, the MonitoringStep entity is not updated in the background worker.

Below you can see the codes of the method I created for the background worker:

```
        var monitorRepository = workerContext.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMonitorRepository>();

        var monitor = await monitorRepository.GetAsync(Guid.Parse("E3076832-D653-79BC-002B-39F8403C4EB0"));

        monitor.SetName("stackoverflow-example");
        monitor.MonitorStep.Url = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
        
        await monitorRepository.UpdateAsync(monitor, true);
```

As a result, the Name property in the Monitor table is updated, but the Url in the MonitorStep table is not updated.

Below you can see the exception that occurred during saving and the content of my entity.

[image]

[image]

I think there is something I'm missing, can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps providing your mapping of Monitor and MonitorStep would make it easier to help you, nevertheless, with the information provided, I'd point out to two things: 1 -> Your MonitorStep is not correctly mapped in EF. 2 -> You need to Attach your MonitorStep object to the context, since EF core does not use lazy loading as its default  behaviour anymore, you are getting your Monitor object, but the database is not tracking the changes in your MonitorStep object.

Comment: I think I have already done what you say. You can check [here](https://github.com/berkansasmaz/ketum/blob/dev/src/Ketum.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/KetumDbContextModelCreatingExtensions.cs) if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could understand from your code in [here](https://github.com/berkansasmaz/ketum/blob/dev/src/Ketum.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/KetumDbContextModelCreatingExtensions.cs) and according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#other-relationship-patterns) and [this website](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-one-relationship-configuration) there are two issues, one; a property is missing in the MonitorStep class:

```
    public Monitor Monitor { get; set; }
```

Second, since you are mapping a one-to-one relationship, your mapping is missing the reference to the one-to-one table/class (Monitor):

```
b.HasOne(n => n.MonitorStep).WithOne(m => m.Monitor).HasForeignKey<MonitorStep>(x => x.MonitorId).IsRequired();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that didn't fix my problem.

Comment: If you have any other suggestions I'd love to hear.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In fact, the problem is in the `DbContext.Attach(entity);` line in the `UpdateAsync` method. This line did not save changes until Save Changes was done. I was doing `AutoSave`, actually, I expected that part to work properly but it didn't work. After a long effort, I was able to create a `UnitOfWork` and save the changes thanks to it. Thank you for your answers.